# No communication services enabled following startup

Tags: debian, startup, services

I recently installed Parsix (Debian) on my system, and I've been struggling to figure out how to autostart my services. Of the list of services that don't run and should run are:

- ssh
- apache
- mysql

They run easily enough with the generic: `service ssh start`, and when I run

```
> update-rc.d ssh defaults
 System startup links for /etc/init.d/ssh already exist.
```

As an added note:

```
> service ssh status
[FAIL] sshd is not running ... failed!
```

Edit:
`ls /etc/rc*.d/*ssh*` produces

```
/etc/rc0.d/K50ssh  /etc/rc2.d/K50ssh  /etc/rc4.d/K50ssh  /etc/rc6.d/K50ssh
/etc/rc1.d/K50ssh  /etc/rc3.d/K50ssh  /etc/rc5.d/S50ssh
```

(does K mean "Kill"??)
Also, the current run-level is set to 5.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls /etc/rc*.d/*ssh*`?

Comment: @Karlson... hmm I think you might be on to something

Comment: You seem to have only the kill scripts.  Is `openssh-server` or similar installed?

Comment: @Karlson rc5 is Start, and the openssh works when I start the server

Comment: Sorry didn't pay attention.  That means that your default runlevel isn't 5.  When the machine comes up login as root and do `who -r`

Comment: @Karlson `run-level 5  2013-01-02 16:34                   last=S`

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/daemon.log`, `/var/adm/messages`, and `ps -ef` to check whether or not these services have even been started and whether or not some startup script got stuck?